# Method to sort strings in descending order (in complex keys)

Tags: ruby, string, sorting, reverse

In order to descend-sort an array `a` of strings, `reverse` can be used.

```
a.sort.reverse
```

But when you want to use a string among multiple sort keys, that cannot be done. Suppose `items` is an array of items that have attributes `attr1` (`String`), `attr2` (`String`), `attr3` (`Integer`). Sort can be done like:

```
items.sort_by{|item| [item.attr1, item.attr2, item.attr3]}
```

Switching from ascending to descending can be done independently for `Integer` by multiplying it with `-1`:

```
items.sort_by{|item| [item.attr1, item.attr2, -item.attr3]}
```

But such method is not straightforward for `String`. Can such method be defined? When you want to do descending sort with respect to `attr2`, it should be written like:

```
items.sort_by{|item| [item.attr1, item.attr2.some_method, item.attr3]}
```

Comment: Why not use `sort` in such cases? Probably clearer than some funky mess of complexity just so you can keep using `sort_by`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can always convert your strings into an array of integers (`ord`). Like this:

```
strings = [["Hello", "world"], ["Hello", "kitty"], ["Hello", "darling"]]
strings.sort_by do |s1, s2|
  [
    s1,
    s2.chars.map(&:ord).map{ |n| -n }
  ]
end
```

PS:

As @CarySwoveland caught here is a corner case with empty string, which could be solved with this non elegant solution:

```
strings.sort_by do |s1, s2|
  [
    s1,
    s2.chars.
       map(&:ord).
       tap{|chars| chars << -Float::INFINITY if chars.empty? }.
       map{ |n| -n }
  ]
end
```

And @Jordan kindly mentioned that [sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) uses [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) so you don't need preprocessing at all.

Comment: I think this is the simplest one.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with empty strings. Suppose `strings = [["a",""], ["a","a"]]` and we want a decreasing sort on the second element of each array. Since `"" < "a" #=> true` it should return `[["a", "a"], ["a", ""]]` but it returns the reverse. Though a little klutzy, perhaps `h[s2] = s2.empty? ? [Float::INFINITY] : s2.chars.map{ |s| -s.ord }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland good catch! You could solve it with this workaround `h[s2] = s2.chars.map{ |s| -s.ord }.tap{ |chars| chars << -Float::INFINITY if chars.empty? }`

Comment: I believe that's `chars << Float::INFINITY...`. Perhaps edit rather than comment.

Comment: This is the same as my solution posted a couple hours earlier, except that I used `codepoints` instead of `chars.map(&:ord)`. Preprocessing seems like a good idea but I think it makes more sense to build a Hash on-the-fly with e.g. `hm = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = k.chars.map {|c| -c.ord } }`.

Comment: Actually, since `sort_by` does a Schwartzian Transform does preprocessing actually save any time?

Comment: @Jordan, you are totally right (I didn't know about this Transform). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The following supports all objects that respond to `<=>`.

```
def generalized_array_sort(arr, inc_or_dec)
  arr.sort do |a,b|
    comp = 0
    a.zip(b).each_with_index do |(ae,be),i|
      next if (ae<=>be).zero?
      comp = (ae<=>be) * (inc_or_dec[i]==:inc ? 1 : -1)
      break
    end
    comp
  end
end
```

*Example*

```
arr = [[3, "dog"], [4, "cat"], [3, "cat"], [4, "dog"]]
inc_or_dec = [:inc, :dec] 

generalized_array_sort(arr, inc_or_dec)
  #=> [[3, "dog"], [3, "cat"], [4, "dog"], [4, "cat"]]
```

*Another example*

```
class A; end
class B<A; end
class C<B; end
[A,B,C].sort #=> [C, B, A] 

arr = [[3, A], [4, B], [3, B], [4, A], [3, C], [4,C]]
inc_or_dec = [:inc, :dec] 

generalized_array_sort(arr, inc_or_dec)
  #=> [[3, A], [3, B], [3, C], [4, A], [4, B], [4, C]]
```

Comment: This solution implements @muistooshort's comment on the question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure either of these passes your straightforwardness test, but I think both work correctly. Using @CarySwoveland's test data:

```
arr = [[3, "dog"], [4, "cat"], [3, "cat"], [4, "dog"]]

arr.sort_by {|a, b| [ a, *b.codepoints.map(&:-@) ] }
# => [[3, "dog"], [3, "cat"], [4, "dog"], [4, "cat"]]
```

Alternatively, here's a solution that works regardless of the type (i.e. it needn't be a string):

```
arr.sort do |a, b|
  c0 = a[0] <=> b[0]
  next c0 unless c0.zero?
  -(a[1] <=> b[1])
end
# => [[3, "dog"], [3, "cat"], [4, "dog"], [4, "cat"]]
```

The latter could be generalized as a method like so:

```
def arr_cmp(a, b, *dirs)
  return 0 if a.empty? && b.empty?
  return a <=> b if dirs.empty?
  a0, *a = a
  b0, *b = b
  dir, *dirs = dirs
  c0 = a0 <=> b0
  return arr_cmp(a, b, *dirs) if c0.zero?
  dir * c0
end
```

This works just like `<=>` but as its final arguments takes a list of `1` or `-1`s indicating to the sort directions for each respective array element, e.g.:

```
a = [3, "dog"]
b = [3, "cat"]
arr_cmp(a, b, 1, 1) # => 1
arr_cmp(a, b, 1, -1) # => -1
```

Like `<=>` it's most useful in a `sort` block:

```
arr.sort {|a, b| arr_cmp(a, b, 1, -1) }
# => [[3, "dog"], [3, "cat"], [4, "dog"], [4, "cat"]]
```

I haven't tested it much, though, so there are probably edge cases for which it fails.

Comment: If `arr = [[3, "dog"], [4, ""], [3, ""], [4, "dog"]]`, `arr.sort_by {|a, b| [ a, *b.codepoints.map(&:-@) ] } #=> [[3, ""], [3, "dog"], [4, ""], [4, "dog"]]`, which is incorrect. It seems like all methods that convert strings to numbers need to treat empty strings as a special case, perhaps mapping them to `Float::INFINITY`.

Answer (score 1):

While I have no idea about generic academic implementation, in the real life I would go with:

```
class String 
  def hash_for_sort precision = 5
    (@h_f_p ||= {})[precision] ||= self[0...precision].codepoints.map do |cp|
      [cp, 99999].min.to_s.ljust 5, '0'
    join.to_i
  end
end
```

Now feel free to sort by `-item.attr2.hash_for_sort`.

The approach above has some glitches:

- no valid sorting for the strings, that differ in `> precision` letters;
- initial call to the function is `O(self.length)`;
- codepoints above 99999 would be considered equal (sorting is not accurate).

But taking into account the real circumstanses, I can not imagine when this won’t suffice.

*P.S.* If I were to solve this task precisely, I would search for an algorithm, converting strings to floats in a one-to-one manner.